# Why does perspective on transformed elements appear backwards?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmnja/) you can play with. Move around the rotateX and rotateY sliders to see. The part of the element that is closest to you is smaller while the part that is farther away is bigger. If you flip it around using

```
transform:rotateZ(180deg);
```

it looks right but I don't understand why it doesnt just look right in the first place.

[image]

**update**

it makes sense if you look at [this 3d cube](http://jsfiddle.net/dLKsd/). *the transform origin of the cube is the middle of the cube.*

Comment: how or why is this off topic? every user listed below who closed this as off topic is weak sauce. provide an answer or reasoning behind your holier than thou prerogatives

Comment: thx for sticking up for the validity of the question.

Comment: @thinkingstiff "stop putting that crap at the top of it" what an in-depth and intuitive answer. we can all learn from that!

Comment: no he's right. i started raging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Isometric

As far as I can tell the methods work as they are suppose to, it's just that they are rotated in isometric 3D, that is without perspective. This will make your closest and further edges will have the same size, unlike real 3D where the further edge will look smaller and the closer will look bigger.

For a in depth look at isometric projection give the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) a read.

## Perspective

If you want to get perspective on the rotations you have to add the `perspective` property to your CSS for the containing element. If you add `-webkit-perspective: 1000px;`to `<body>` in your first fiddle and view the result in Chrome you'll get perspective 3D like you probably wanted.

More info on that property can be found in the [CSS3 transform spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#perspective-property).

Comment: after taking a second look at this property this is eventually what worked. weirdly, it only worked once applied it to the parent of the container.